Drawing two planes in space, highlighting the intersection line
So, I'm stuck on this drawing: I have to draw two planes of equations x+y+z = 2 and x+y-z = 1, highlighting the line obtained by their intersection. This is what I wrote so far. I'm not happy, it looks like a messy drawing...
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrreport}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[ 
view={60}{30}, % Sight angle in 3D
axis lines=middle, 
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$, 
width=12cm, height=12cm, 
grid=both, 
major grid style={thin, draw=black!50}, 
minor grid style={dashed, draw=black!30}, 
domain=-3:3, y domain=-3:3, 
samples=30, 
enlarge y limits={abs=1cm}, 
enlarge x limits={abs=1cm}, 
xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty

% x + y + z = 2 gray plane
\addplot3[
surf, 
opacity=0.3, 
gray
]
{2 - x - y}; 

% x + y - z = 1 yellow plane
\addplot3[
surf, 
opacity=0.3, 
yellow
]
{x + y - 1}; 

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}

I would like to clearly see the intersection line. There is no need of writings or labels. Also maybe is the angle viev that makes me feel it's a weird drawing?
Help me to clean this a bit please. Thank you!

The intersection line has the parametric representation x = 3/2 - t, y = t, z = 1/2 if you need this too. It's also contained in the plane parallel to the xy plane.


EDIT
I tried in this other way, but I'm not satisfied either. The intersection is not clear, despite the line is highlighted. I don't like the framebox also.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-20:30]
\addplot3[surf, opacity=0.25, cyan, shader=flat] {2-x-y};
\addplot3[surf, opacity=0.25, yellow, shader=flat] {x+y-1};
\addplot3+[domain=-20:20, samples=80, samples y=0, mark=none,     black, opacity=0.5, thick]({x},{(3/2 - x},{0.});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



Note that pgfplots is incapable of automatically layering separate surfaces - you have to layer them yourself. You can do it in tikz using this idea: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730409/319072.

pgfplots makes two mistakes in graphing surfaces, in my opinion. (1) it should use triangles instead of squares, because four points may be noncoplanar, and (2) it shouldn't draw the grid on the planes.

@Jasper It's what I tried to do in the second case, highlighting the line myself. I'm not happy with both the results, and I don't find anything useful over here nor elsewhere. I cannot understand why it must be so difficult to draw a simple thing like this...

@hHenry I agree that this should be easier for people to do.

This is the best I can do right now. I am open to feedback on any way to improve the approach. We can scale the diagram with the solutionin https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/731044/319072.
The .sty for pline is available from my https://github.com/Pseudonym321/LaTeX_Repository/blob/master1/TikZ/packages/pline.sty.
Caution: Iwrote this myslef
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pline}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]

    % For \drawbox, all of the mins and maxes are defaulted to -5 and 5. 
    % Labels are added manually, the marks are at one quarter and three quarters along the box lengths.
    % I can't automate their labelling for all perspectives yet, so it will remain manual.
    \drawbox[
        xmin=-4
        ,xmax=4
        ,ymax=10
        ,zmax=3
    ]

    % This is a way to manually add labels.
    \LabelPath{4,-5,-5}{0,{10-(-5)},0}{0.25}{0ex}{-3ex}{$\pgfmathparse{-5+0.25*(10-(-5))}\pgfmathresult$}
    \LabelPath{4,-5,-5}{0,{10-(-5)},0}{0.75}{0ex}{-3ex}{$\pgfmathparse{-5+0.75*(10-(-5))}\pgfmathresult$}

    \LabelPath{-4,10,-5}{{4-(-4)},0,0}{0.25}{0ex}{3ex}{$\pgfmathparse{-4+0.25*(4-(-4))}\pgfmathresult$}
    \LabelPath{-4,10,-5}{{4-(-4)},0,0}{0.75}{0ex}{3ex}{$\pgfmathparse{-4+0.75*(4-(-4))}\pgfmathresult$}

    \LabelPath{4,-5,-5}{0,0,{3-(-5)}}{0.25}{0ex}{3ex}{$\pgfmathparse{-5+0.25*(3-(-5))}\pgfmathresult$}
    \LabelPath{4,-5,-5}{0,0,{3-(-5)}}{0.75}{0ex}{3ex}{$\pgfmathparse{-5+0.75*(3-(-5))}\pgfmathresult$}



    % Pline lets you save the path of the outline of a plane, clipped by a rectangular prism of your choosing. 
    % It also lets you calculate the line of intersection between two (intersecting) planes.
    % With the paths of two planes, and their intersection, we can use spath3 to split them at their intersections into four half planes.
    % We can then manually add those half planes in order to achieve a perspective picture.
    % I intend to automate this one day so this can be animated for varying perspective angles.
    \getPlane{1}{1}{1}{2}{Pone}
    \getPlane{1}{1}{-1}{1}{Ptwo}
    \getLine{1}{1}{1}{2}{1}{1}{-1}{1}{Lint}
    
    \begin{scope}
        % it is good to clip the path of the planes in a scope, due to a "feature" of the coordinate calculations.
        \clip[spath/use=Ptwo];

        % This is how we split the plane by its intersection with the other plane.
        \scoped[
            spath/split at intersections={Ptwo}{Lint},
            spath/remove components={Ptwo}{1},
            ]
        % Finally, we draw the half plane.
        \fill[green, opacity=0.6]
            (spath cs:{Ptwo} 1) [spath/use={Ptwo}]
                                [spath/use={Lint, reverse}]
            -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

    % We don't need to split the red plane due to the perspective angle, so we just draw it.
    \fill[red, opacity=0.6, spath/use=Pone];

    % Finally, we draw the side of the green plane which is facing us.
    \begin{scope}
        \clip[spath/use=Ptwo];
        \scoped[
            spath/split at intersections={Ptwo}{Lint},
            spath/remove components={Ptwo}{0},
            ]
        \fill[green, opacity=0.6]
            (spath cs:{Ptwo} 1) [spath/use={Ptwo}]
                                [spath/use={Lint, reverse}]
            -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    
    \draw[blue, spath/use=Lint];

    %\labelPath{}
        
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


